# Generar estructura en flexbox bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```css
.columns-equal {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
height:800px

}

.col-bordered {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    flex: 0 1 50%;
}

.col-bordered div {
    flex: 1;
}

.row-acc-1 {
    background-color: green
}

.row-acc-2 {
    background-color: red
}

.col-bordered {
    border: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row columns-equal">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-bordered">
        <div class="row row-acc-1">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <figure>
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/238615749" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>
              </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-acc-2">
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/radiocantilo/html/images/picurba-banner.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="row row-acc-2" style="background-color: blue">
          <a>Test 2</a>
        </div>
      </div>        
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-bordered">
        <span>
          Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>      
</section>
  
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[image: .]
Hola como generaria esta estructura en bootstrap con flexbox y a la ves que sea responsive

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos el código que has intentado ?

Comment: ahi edite con el código que estaba probando

Comment: @MarianoFranco pero ejecutando tu snippet veo que tienes algo parecido...

Comment: ahí pude hacerlo ahora el problema es caundo en una de las cajas inserto un video como logro adaptar su height en los modos responsive. @CamiloVasquez

Comment: edite de nuevo el snippet

Comment: @MarianoFranco quieres que las cajas mantengan su altura sin importar ? no entiendo muy bien que quieres lograr

Comment: yo lo que necesito es que en las columnas de la izquierda haya un video de vimeo, un banner de una imagen en la ultima un titulo el video y la imagen del banner deberian mantener las proporciones a la hora de hacer responsive por eso las cajas deberían adaptarse al contenido que va dentro de cada caja. me pasaba que cuando ponía un video en el primero y lo miraba en versiones mobile no se adaptaba y se veia el color de esa caja que le puse para identificarla. se comprende?

Comment: @MarianoFranco acabo de hacer una prueba en mi entorno local y esta bien en móvil ... sigo sin entender que quieres yo veo que si se adapta, si deseas agrega una imagen de como lo vez tu o algo así

Comment: Hola perdon por contestar tarde, ahí agregue una imagen al maquetado.

Comment: http://qkstudiodemo.com/radiocantilo/html/ acá te paso el link de como quedo, lo que no me agrada es la instacia de 768 px mobile donde dice lo ultimo ya ahora que me deja por debajo un blanco grande. @CamiloVasquez

Answer (score 0):

Yo le quitaría el `display: flex` a la columna izquierda ya que realmente no lo necesitas, con esto lograrás que tanto el padre directo de la imagen y el video se adapten en altura al tamaño de sus hijos:

```css
.columns-equal {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.columns-equal .row img{
  width: 100%;
}

.row-acc-1 {
  background-color: green
height:400px
}

.row-acc-2 {
  background-color: red
}

.col-bordered {
  border: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row columns-equal">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-bordered">
        <div class="row row-acc-1">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <figure>
                <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/238615749" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>
              </figure>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row row-acc-2">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/radiocantilo/html/images/picurba-banner.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="row row-acc-2" style="background-color: blue">
          <a>Test 2</a>
        </div>
      </div>        
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-bordered">
        <span>
          Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>      
</section>
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Entonces vos decís que esta de gusto el flex ese? que no tiene sentido que lo use? estaba mirando el ejemplo de este sitio http://www.vorterix.com/ que es muy parecido a lo que yo plantee, en las instancias mobile lo que es tablet por ahí es mas recomendable que use los bloques uno debajo del otro no? mas que nada por el diseño de este tipo de cajas que son flexibles.

Comment: Lo único que necesitas flexible es el contenedor general de la sección, ¿para que vas a hacer flexible algo que tiene 3 hijos y siempre van a estar uno debajo del otro? .... en la página que acabas de mostrar veo que usan posiciones (relativas y absolutas) display:table y <table>...

Comment: claro! bueno voy a seguir probando esto, gracias por el aporte camilo.

Comment: @MarianoFranco si necesitas algo más me dices, revisa mi ejemplo que ahí el video y la imagen se adaptan solos

Comment: Si si lo estuve mirando camilo. gracias!

Comment: @MarianoFranco la edición que acabas de hacer no puede ser aceptada por que esta "claramente en conflicto con la intención del autor"

Comment: Camilo perdona que te moleste, ahí volví a editar la pregunta, quería hacerte una consulta. yo tengo el vídeo y quiero hacerlo mas grande, darle un alto de 420px, resulta que me pasa que a la caja le puedo dar ese alto de 420px pero cuando quiero darle un alto al vídeo no me deja. lo que hice tambien es achicar el banner. te muestro el ej en este link para que lo veas mas claro. http://qkstudiodemo.com/radiocantilo/v3/

Comment: ahh perdon! pensé que había editado el mio.

Comment: @MarianoFranco el video no lo puedes redimencionar de esa forma por que estarías dañando sis dimenciones originales

Comment: pero hay alguna forma de poder determinarle un alto? se puede hacer de alguna forma? el video esta encerrado en div con la caja que le determina un alto, luego le sigue un embed-responsive, un figure que por ahi esta de gusto, y el iframe que solamente le deje como determinado un width de 100%. si le doy un height al iframe me genera como un margen top por arriba

Comment: @MarianoFranco si la hay yo no la conozco, usualmente nunca he tratado de deformar un video por lo cual no te tengo una respuesta ante eso